# how to create and match schema in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, schema

Hi i have a schema coming in as follows

```
|-- eventObject: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- baseDivisionCode: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- countryCode: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- dcNumber: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- financialReportingGroup: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- itemList: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- availabletosellQty: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- distroAvailableQty: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- itemNumber: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- itemUPC: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- ossIndicator: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- turnAvailableQty: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- unitOfMeasurement: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- weightFormatType: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- whpkRatio: long (nullable = true)
```

to map this i have create this following schema type

```
|-- eventObject: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- baseDivisionCode: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- countryCode: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- dcNumber: integer (nullable = true)
|    |-- financialReportingGroup: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- itemList: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- availabletosellQty: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- distroAvailableQty: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- itemNumber: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- itemUPC: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- ossIndicator: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- turnAvailableQty: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- unitOfMeasurement: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- weightFormatType: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- whpkRatio: long (nullable = true)
```

by writing something like this

```
 val testSchema = new StructType()
  .add("eventObject", new StructType()
    .add("baseDivisionCode", StringType)
    .add("countryCode",StringType)
    .add("dcNumber", IntegerType)
    .add("financialReportingGroup",StringType)

    .add("itemList",new StructType(
      Array(
        StructField("availabletosellQty",LongType),
        StructField("distroAvailableQty",LongType),
        StructField("itemNumber", LongType),
        StructField("itemUPC", StringType),
        StructField("ossIndicator",StringType),
        StructField("turnAvailableQty",LongType),
        StructField("unitOfMeasurement",StringType),
        StructField("weightFormatType",StringType),
        StructField("whpkRatio",LongType)))))
```

but it is not matching the schema that i am receiving...what am i doing wrong in this?

i am getting null values when i try to populate the with some data...

```
|-- eventObject: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- baseDivisionCode: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- countryCode: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- dcNumber: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- financialReportingGroup: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- itemList: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- itemNumber: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- itemUPC: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- unitOfMeasurement: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- availabletosellQty: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- turnAvailableQty: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- distroAvailableQty: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- ossIndicator: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- weightFormatType: string (nullable = true)
|-- kafka_timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)

|-- baseDivisionCode: string (nullable = true)
|-- countryCode: string (nullable = true)
|-- dcNumber: long (nullable = true)
|-- financialReportingGroup: string (nullable = true)
|-- itemList: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- itemNumber: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- itemUPC: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- unitOfMeasurement: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- availabletosellQty: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- turnAvailableQty: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- distroAvailableQty: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- ossIndicator: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- weightFormatType: string (nullable = true)
|-- kafka_timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

when i further try to flatten it, its erroring out cause of array
"Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(itemList)`;"

trying to get it to

```
|-- facilityCountryCode: string (nullable = true)
|-- facilityNum: string (nullable = true)
|-- WMT_CorrelationId: string (nullable = true)
|-- WMT_IdempotencyKey: string (nullable = true)
|-- WMT_Timestamp: string (nullable = true)
|-- countryCode: string (nullable = true)
|-- dcNumber: integer (nullable = true)
|-- financialReportingGroup: string (nullable = true)
|-- baseDivisionCode: string (nullable = true)
|-- itemNumber: integer (nullable = true)
|-- itemUPC: string (nullable = true)
|-- unitOfMeasurement: string (nullable = true)
|-- availabletosellQty: integer (nullable = true)
|-- turnAvailableQty: integer (nullable = true)
|-- distroAvailableQty: integer (nullable = true)
|-- ossIndicator: string (nullable = true)
|-- weightFormatType: string (nullable = true)
|-- kafka_timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- year-month-day: integer (nullable = true)
|-- month: integer (nullable = true)
|-- day: integer (nullable = true)
|-- hour: integer (nullable = true)
```

this is what i did

```
val testParsed=TestExploded.select($"exploded.*",$"kafka_timestamp")

val testFlattened=testParsed.select($"eventObject.*",$"kafka_timestamp")

val test_flattened_further=testFlattened.select($"countryCode",
  $"dcNumber",$"financialReportingGroup",$"baseDivisionCode",**$"itemList.*"**,$"kafka_timestamp")
```

Comment: You converted `itemList` from `array[struct]` to `struct`. How are you supposed to do that? By taking the Nth element from array?

Comment: no, i need the array[struct]...i need all the elements from list

Comment: So you only need to convert all the `long` type fields to `integers`?

Comment: no, i need to create a schema which matches the schema i am receiving...i am not sure on how to add that  |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) in my schema

Comment: Your first and schema don't match. itemList is an Array of Struct in first whereas just Struct in second schema. Can you please revisit your input and expected schema?

Comment: @Belwal yes i am trying to match them both, not sure of what i am doing wrong..i have created an array of itemList..but it is coming as struct and not array[struct] , what changes should i make to testSchema to match it with first schema?

Comment: You just need to wrap StructType() within ArrayType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ArrayType` to specify array type:

```
val testSchema = new StructType()
    .add("eventObject", new StructType()
    .add("baseDivisionCode", StringType)
    .add("countryCode", StringType)
    .add("dcNumber", LongType)
    .add("financialReportingGroup", StringType)
    .add("itemList", new ArrayType(
      new StructType(
        Array(
          StructField("itemNumber", LongType),
          StructField("itemUPC", StringType),
          StructField("unitOfMeasurement", StringType),
          StructField("availabletosellQty", LongType),
          StructField("turnAvailableQty", LongType),
          StructField("distroAvailableQty", LongType),
          StructField("ossIndicator", StringType),
          StructField("weightFormatType", StringType))), containsNull = true)))
```

To fully flatten the `DataFrame` you can use explode array of structs and move struct type into top level columns by `select("structColName.*")` syntax as follows:

```
df
  .select("eventObject.*")
  .select(
    col("baseDivisionCode"),
    col("countryCode"),
    col("dcNumber"),
    col("financialReportingGroup"),
    explode(col("itemList")).as("explodedItemList"))
  .select(
    col("baseDivisionCode"),
    col("countryCode"),
    col("dcNumber"),
    col("financialReportingGroup"),
    col("explodedItemList.*")
  )
  .printSchema()
```

Will output:

```
root
 |-- baseDivisionCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- countryCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dcNumber: long (nullable = true)
 |-- financialReportingGroup: string (nullable = true)
 |-- itemNumber: long (nullable = true)
 |-- itemUPC: string (nullable = true)
 |-- unitOfMeasurement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- availabletosellQty: long (nullable = true)
 |-- turnAvailableQty: long (nullable = true)
 |-- distroAvailableQty: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ossIndicator: string (nullable = true)
 |-- weightFormatType: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: thanks @Duelist , this is mapping my schema with incoming schema.but i think it wont be flattened, before i was able to flatten the schema...

Comment: What do you mean by flattening the schema?

Comment: updated the question with the results..could you please look at that.

Comment: So you need to turn `eventObject` struct into top level columns? If so, this can be achieved by `df.select("eventObject.*")`